# Visual Studio 2015 - Multiple Instances of Node.js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015

I am currently experiencing a strange issue with Node.js within Visual Studio.

I'm currently working on multiple projects (containing many typescript files - i've read elsewhere this could possibly have something to do with my problem) in Visual Studio 2015 (Version 4.7.02053).  I have node.js (v 6.10.0) installed on my dev machine also.  Currently we are using the built in TypeScript compiler within visual studio (previously using grunt for ts compilation, now just for sass).

I've also configured visual studio to use the current version of node I have installed (please see screenshot below):

[Custom Path to node.js installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqAIm.png)

My issue is this, whenever I open one of my projects, multiple, I mean a lot, I mean like between 50-100 node.exe processes spin up, please see the image below!

[Lot's of node processes, seems to be update-notifier\check.js???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNfKM.png)

This is eating away at my CPU and rendering my machine barely usable, especially when i have three or four separate projects open at the same time.

I've attempted to google a fix for this but haven't come up with anything that has worked thus far, so, any help you could possibly give me is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have to do with the update-notifier package.